# Considerations about associative arrays in PLSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, loops, plsql

I'm learn PLSQL Collections and now I'm practicing associativa Arrays, first step, I've used PLSQL Methods for collections (FIRST, LAST, COUNT, PRIOR) and I've coded a simple LOOP for print on screen all the information within associative variable. It's a simple example about players of a random football team but I don´t understand the steps to code a loop using collections. This Loop is working fine but I don't understand the procedure to create a associative Array Loop. I need considerations and "theory" about this PLSQL resources. Thanks.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE spurs_players_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(45)
       INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  v_spurs_2006 spurs_players_type;

  v_spurs_numero PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_spurs_2006(1)  := 'Robinson';
  v_spurs_2006(2)  := 'Chimbonda';
  v_spurs_2006(3)  := 'Young';
  v_spurs_2006(4)  := 'Zokora';
  v_spurs_2006(5)  := 'Davids';
  v_spurs_2006(6)  := 'Taino';
  v_spurs_2006(7)  := 'Stalteri';
  v_spurs_2006(8)  := 'Jenas';
  v_spurs_2006(10) := 'Keane';
  v_spurs_2006(20) := 'Dawson';
  v_spurs_2006(22) := 'Huddlestone';
  v_spurs_2006(25) := 'Lennon';
  v_spurs_2006(26) := 'King';
  v_spurs_2006(35) := 'Dervite';

v_spurs_numero := v_spurs_2006.LAST;

  WHILE v_spurs_numero IS NOT NULL
  LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of player ' ||
                             v_spurs_2006(v_spurs_numero) || ' is ' ||
                             v_spurs_numero);
        v_spurs_numero := v_spurs_2006.PRIOR (v_spurs_numero);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking - you don't understand the code you have written; or you now want to do something else (what?) and don't know how/it isn't working? The 'theory' is in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#CHDEIDIC)...

Comment: This is the point. I don't understand the code you have written!!! I can´t understand why I have to write after DBMS_OUTPUT... "v_spurst :=....PRIOR (v_spurs_numero); I understand how loop works and I have written a lot of loop with simple variables "variable_name table.column%TYPE" but now It's very difficult understand LOOP for associative Varrays. I need something like a resume or text tutorial about how the associative loop works. Thanks for reply my post.

Answer (score 0):

.LAST and .PRIOR are collection methods, check the docs below:
[Collection Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/plsql-collections-and-records.htm#LNPLS00508)